# Why is my MathJax formatting so messed up?

Tags: bug, markdown, mathjax

Just look at this mess.

The following source:

```
We have $G$ solvable, so that we can find a tower of subgroups 
$$
G = G_0 \supset G_1 \supset\cdots\supset G_m = 1
$$
so that the conditions on solvability are met. We then take the quotient so that
$$
G/H = (G/H)_0\supset (G/H)_1 \supset\cdots\supset (G/H)_m = 1
$$
where $(G/H)_j = G_j/H$. It is then immediately verified that all factor groups in this tower are abelian, as $(G_i/H)/(G_{i+1}/H) = G_i/G_{i+1}$, which is abelian by assumption.
```

renders as

[image: Donald Knuth wants to know your location]

The problem begins with the first $$ math block. I suspect that there is some kind of conflict between the underscores being used by LaTeX for subscript and by markup for italics, because before MathJax renders the LaTeX code, the preview looks like this:

[image: I don't want these italics]

Where all text between the underscore that is supposed to make the *m* next to the last (G/H) subscript and the underscore that is supposed to make the {*i*+1} right at the end subscript is now in italics.

How do I get around this? I need there to be underscores so that my indices are properly placed and in line with the notation from the literature from which this is taken. Using regular inline math (single $) instead of block math (double $$) does not fix the issue.

Comment: [I can't reproduce it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35923/228959)

Comment: What site is this?

Comment: It reproduces in the preview at <https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask> and <https://mathoverflow.net/questions/ask>, but not in <https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/35923/edit>.

Comment: (That said, I may need to update my answer over there…)

Comment: @user3840170 that fixed it, thanks!

Comment: (There is a trailing space after *"subgroups"*.)